# Enjoy the delicacy of the food

Tags: grammaticality

May I know if the following is grammatical?

> Enjoy the delicacy of the food

Comment: You as a user with five gold badges, you should know that proofreading is generally discouraged here :)

Comment: If you provide more information about the question, for example identifying any specific concerns about the question, it might not be closed as proofreading.

Comment: I actually disagree that this is just a proofreading question, although it certainly dances on the line of being one.  *Delicacy* has several meanings, and it might not be apparent to a learner if it can be used this way.

Comment: Though we can guess, pointing out the word in question would be appropriate, along with some research into its definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking about the fineness of the food then **"yes"** this is absolutely correct grammatically and logically. But if you are speaking about a *"rare or expensive food item that is considered highly desirable, sophisticated or peculiarly distinctive, within a given culture"* then this isn't grammatical and it should be rephrased. In this case **"delicacy"** often precedes or is followed by a label, country, place and e.t.c.

- Enjoy this traditional English delicacy.
- Please try our national Korean delicacies.

Comment: I admire your kindness to provide good answers in this site. But before you get criticized, I recommend you not [feed the bear](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears) in future :-)

Comment: @user178049 I admire you concern, however, I, as a Russian simple folk, wish to give my best knowledge in sake of OPs understanding. I notice the flag zone in the questions, but I remember the way I sometimes ask questions and the way I started asking them here. I wish not everyone would be so straight forward to the rules on the site.